# Rails/Rspec Views: The right way to test partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have a Rails 3 partial that lists all categories as a navigation menu - it's on most, but not all of my template pages...let's say about 75%. I'm trying to test the partial (in RSpec) right now, and I've just realised a few things:

At the moment, I'm calling Categories.all in the actual view. The difficulty is that, because that touches the database, my mocks/stubs in the view spec are ignored, and consequently the test fails.

I'm guessing the alternative is to assign the variable in the application controller, and then pass it as a local variable to the partial. Still, about 25% of my pages won't use the variable and I'm wondering if there's a more graceful way of doing things.

In short, I want view specs to pass without touching the test DB, but I'm not sure a global variable passed to my partial is the best way to do it...and I'm not declaring the variable in every (& only) those controllers who require it.

Any suggestions appreciated...

Comment: I have this question too. It would be helpful to see a code snippet of the spec file and perhaps the view too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a helper method for all categories?

```
  # in categories helper

def all_categories
  @all_categories ||= Category.all
end
```

Or...

```
# application controller

helper_method :all_categories

def all_categories 
...
```

You can then stub out this method in your specs and you won't be touching the DB